# Reset MOSS admin Password

Tags: 2007

I just joined a company where some individual has created a MOSS 2007 portal. He created a local administrator level account on domain. Somehow nobody remembers the password of that account. If I will reset the password from Windows 2003 server of moss.admin what consequences I can face? or how to tackle this situation. Please guide.

Comment: a proper admin account shold have no services running using it. or is central admin's application pool running under that account?

Comment: djeeg how to figure this out? can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: [Change Service Accounts and Service Account Passwords in Sharepoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838)

Not that hard to find IMHO!